# Can we create a table using JPA QueryDSL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I am using JPA QueryDSL to query data from DB, which works great.
Now i have a complex select query written in JPA QueryDSL using which i need to create a temporary table like below (POSTGRES).

```
create TEMP table temp as (select * from XYZ.)
```

Can anyone help with with how to define the above query using JPA QueryDSL.
Is it possible to handle DDL with JPA QueryDSL?

Your suggestions to my problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible within the existing framework. I would strongly suggest that creating tables in the application layer is a bad idea. A JPA entity class would have to created at runtime, etc. etc. Could you create a standard table in your schema and use that for the temp data, emptying it out at the end of the run?

Comment: select * from XYZ. is completely dynamic. especially the number of columns sometimes can be 20 or up to 130 as well.

Comment: There is a very large table which we are having difficulty in querying. Since the queries are taking too long to respond we thought of this approach. Instead of querying directly to the large table, we thought of creating a new temporary table with this select query and directly querying from there.

Comment: So instead of using JPA, i am using plain JDBC for creating temporary table.

Comment: Have you looked into tuning the query, possibly adding indexes?

Comment: The query already have index. Let me know what can happen if i keep create Local temporary tables from Application level. Will it impact the overall performance. Why do you think it is a bad idea? if it is just about memory then 64 GB is allocated for temporary tables. Also we are dropping them immediately after a thread.

Comment: Temporary tables are only visible to the connection which created it. Say the application used connection pooling and different connections attempted to access the table, it won't work. If it's just one connection, you will be OK but still feels like a bit of a dirty approach. When you say "the query already have index", I'm sure you mean the tables already have indexes but can you tune the query by adding other indexes? (look up postgres EXPLAIN) A quick win is looking for full table scans and adding an index.